# Access Database - Understand Pass Through

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have been given an Access Database that I have to try to decipher what it is doing.

As a start I see that there is a Pass Through query with a command like:

```
Exec RefreshGLTableLatestEntries
 @sourceDB = 'DB_NAME' , 
 @tablePrefix = 'TableName$' ,
 @logFile = 'C:\logDB.txt'
```

When I run it I will get something like:

```
Result
Success... 108 rows inserted with a total amount of $0.000000
```

What I don't understand is where are the rows being copied from or copied to.

In the MSSQL database I don't see a table, query, standard procedure or function called 'TableName$'. There are quite a few tables & queries called 'TableName$SomethingElse'. Is there a way to see more details on where is the data coming from?

Similarly, how can I see where are the rows being inserted to? I can not find any file named 'logDB.txt' in my hard disk to see the log. I would suspect that it might not say much more that '...108 rows insterted...'

I'm using:

- Access 2016 from Office 365, Version 1609
- MS SQL Server Management Studio v17.1

Any ideas on how to get more information on how to get more information on what the Pass Through do?

Comment: `RefreshGLTableLatestEntries` is the stored procedure that is executed. You need to locate and analyze it.

Comment: In Access or MSSQL?

Comment: The stored procedure is in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Pass-Through query in Access is equivalent to running its SQL code in SQL Server Management Studio.
(In the database that is designated by the connection string of the Pass-Through query.)

The SQL is sent as-is to MSSQL and run there.

`RefreshGLTableLatestEntries` is the stored procedure that is executed here. You need to locate and analyze it in SQL Server.

Comment: I can not find the SP. I can only see System Stored Procedures. If I try to run sp_helptext 'RefreshGLTableLatestEntries' I get  an error message: Msg 15250, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_helptext, Line 44 [Batch Start Line 9]

Comment: Then you're either in the wrong database or on the wrong server, or don't have permissions to see the SP. Check the query's connect string in Access. -- Try running the SQL as shown in your question in SSMS, if it works the SP is there.

Comment: Thanks Andre for your help. I found it in another DB.